# Static final field inheritance in kotlin

Tags: java, class, kotlin

I have a really simple question here, but can't figure it out.
Consider a java class:

```
class A {
    public static final int AA=5;
}
```

which translates (internally) into kotlin as this:

```
open class A {
    companion object {
        val AA:Int=5
    }
}
```

At least that's what I assume.
Now if you inherit in java:

```
class B extends A {
    int AAA;
}
```

you can access field AA (from A) through B like this: B.AA . However, in Kotlin it's impossible. The only way to access it is through A.AA.
Is this a built-in feature or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: The kotlin lines are only the same if you use `const val`.

Comment: yeah, i am sorry. that's from the top of my head. just tried it, still can't seem to get access to the field through the child class.

Comment: Java doesn't have field inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, when the compiler sees `B.AA`, it automatically transforms it into `A.AA`. There's no real inheritance or overriding there.

Kotlin's developers decided not to emulate this feature, because it doesn't fit with thinking of static methods as belonging to an `object`: the companion object of `B` doesn't extend the companion object of `A`, and can't because you can't extend an `object`.

Note that similarly, in Java you can access the field via `a.AA` where `a` is an instance of `A`; you can't do that in Kotlin either.

Comment: that makes sense. my thoughts were along the same lines. however, i was trying to convert a project from java into kotlin and the automatic converter doesn't correct those accessors. in this case it's several data classes. i guess i have to convert them manually. thanks for the tip!

Comment: I suggest checking if this is a known converter bug and reporting if it isn't, at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/.